# CTRL+D doesn't send to the pipe C

Tags: c

I have this program. The program reads a number of numbers from stdin while ctrl+d(EOF) is pressed. The positive numbers goes to a child process, and the negative ones goes to other child process. My question is: why EOF doesn't send to the two processes through pipes?
This is my program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int p0top1[2],p0top2[2];

void tataWork()
{
    int nr;
    FILE *fout1, *fout2;
    fout1 = fdopen(p0top1[1], "w");
    fout2 = fdopen(p0top2[1], "w");
    printf("Begin P0\n");
    while(EOF != scanf("%d", &nr))
    {
        if(nr > 0)
        {
            fprintf(fout1,"%d\n", nr);
            fflush(fout1);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(fout2,"%d\n", nr);
            fflush(fout2);
        }
    }

    close(p0top1[1]);
    close(p0top2[1]);
    printf("Finish P0\n");
}

void p1Work()
{
    close(p0top1[1]);
    printf("Begin P1\n");
    int nr, i, n = 0, sum = 0, vector[1024];
    FILE *fin;
    fin = fdopen(p0top1[0], "r");

    while(EOF != fscanf(fin, "%d", &nr))
    {
        vector[n++] = nr;
        sum += nr;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    close(p0top1[0]);
    printf("Finish P1\n");
}

void p2Work()
{
    close(p0top2[1]);
    printf("Begin P2\n");
    int nr, i, n = 0, sum = 0, vector[1024];
    FILE *fin;
    fin = fdopen(p0top2[0], "r");

    while(EOF != fscanf(fin, "%d", &nr))
    {
        vector[n++] = nr;
        sum += nr;
    }
    printf("I am  P2.\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    close(p0top2[0]);
    printf("Finish P2\n");
}

void makePipe()
{
    if(-1 == pipe(p0top1) )
    {
        perror("Error creating the pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(-1 == pipe(p0top2) )
    {
         perror("Error creating the pipe");
         exit(1);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t p1, p2;

    makePipe();

    if(-1 == (p1=fork()) )
    {
        perror("Error creating the child");
        exit(3);
    }

    if(p1)
    {
        if(-1 == (p2=fork()) )
        {
            perror("Error creating the child");
            exit(4);
        }

        if(p2)
        {
            tataWork();
        }
        else
        {
            p2Work();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        p1Work();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is this:

```
Begin P0
Begin P1
Begin P2
20 -3 4 -2
Finish P0
```

So the children doesn't finish because the EOF isn't send?
Sorry for my bad English!!!

Comment: Look at the condition of your loop.

Comment: Siguza seems ok to me.... Can you tell me what I miss?

Comment: Nvm, I read it wrong. However: both child processes still hold a write descriptor to the other child's pipe. They close the write descriptor to their own pipe, but not the one to the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOF is read from a pipe when all `fd`s pointing to the writing end of the pipe are closed. Both your pipes has three copies of the writing end (one in the main process and one in each of two subprocesses). In your program, you are closing only two of them. In child processes you do not close the pipe which is actually not used by the child (however a copy was created by the `fork` anyway).

Add

```
 close(p0top2[1]);
```

to the beginning of  `p1work` and

```
close(p0top2[1]);
```

to the beginning of `p2Work` and your program will work.

Comment: It's working... I have one more question if you want to answer me... I want to send the sum of the first and second child to the parent... How can I do that? I tried with a other pipe, but it isn't working...  I get the same output... I think it is because the new pipe, but if I close it how can I send it back to the parent?

Comment: @Marius To send results back from child to the main process I'd create another pair of pipes in the main program before `fork`s. You will read results from reading ends in the main process and write to the writing ends in childs.